# Downloaded ubuntu virtual machine for vmbox and mouse & keyboard do not work

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, virtual-machine, mouse

I have downloaded a virtual machine for ubuntu, loaded it into oracle virtual box, and it loads correctly. However I can see my mouse move, but I cannot click on anything, and it does not register my keyboard.

The pointing device is set to "USB tablet", I have tried unselecting and selecting, input devices in user interface section.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The machine is easy to build. Try downloading the Ubuntu ISO and build the machine.  That will install the mouse correctly.

Comment: Turns out it was the wrong graphic driver was selected, it was at vboxsvga instead of vmsvga

Comment: Write this as the answer to help others please.